# Problems with Mongo value-in-array query: $not operator doesn't work, and ObjectIds cannot be selected

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to select a document which does NOT contain a value in a document's array.

I'm having two problems, which I'll present separately:

(1)  I cannot get the $not operator to work with a value-in-array query:
For example, if I have the following document in my collection:

`{ _id: ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
  mylist: [ "red", "green", "blue" ] }`

I can select this document using:

`db.myCol.find({mylist:"red"})`

However, I would like to select this document by testing for the absence of orange:

`db.myCol.find({$not:{mylist:"orange"}})`

Why does this not work?

(2) I cannot get the value in array query to work if the array values are ObjectIds:

`{ _id: Object("000000000000000000000000"),
      mylist: [ ObjectId("111111111111111111111111") ] }`

The following does NOT retrieve this document:

`myCol.find({mylist:ObjectId("111111111111111111111111")})`

Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no [`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/) that works like, you want [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#_S_ne) for simple cases like yours:

```
db.myCol.find({ mylist: { $ne: 'orange' } })
```

Your second should (and does) work fine for me, perhaps you're using the wrong number of ones.

Comment: Not quite true, there is a [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/)

Comment: @nullabletype: Is `$not` something newish or have I just overlooked it? Thanks for the heads up in any case.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could use $not like this:

```
{ 
    "mylist" : {
        $not : { 
            $in : ["red"] 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryarray = ['red']
db.myCol.find({ mylist: { $nin: queryarray  } })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.